# Становиться на дыбы

Tags: этимология

Когда лошадь в порыве эмоций встает на задние ноги, мы говорим, что она становится на дыбы (хотя все конники говорят исключительно "стать на свечу (или на свечку)"). При этом дыбой называется пыточный инструмент, на котором человека растягивали, пока не рвались связки.
Интересно, есть ли связь между этими словами (совершено по смыслу не связанными)? От какого слова они произошли, и что такое эти самые "дыбы"?

Comment: А  ещё  кто-нибудь  на  дыбы  становится?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А  ещё  есть  слово  "одыбать"  в  значении  оправиться  от  болезни.  Лежал,  болел - и  встал  ноги.  Мне  кажется,  что  значение  вертикального  положения  является  исходным. У  Даля  есть  слово  "дыбать"  в  значении  ходить,  шляться  без  дела.  Отсюда,  вероятно  и  слово  "надыбать"  в  значении  найти  что-либо  случайно.  Но  от  "ходить"  до  "принять  вертикальное  положение"  расстояние  невелико.  Фасмер  значение  потверждает,  находит  иноязычных  родственников,  но  исходного  слова  не  даёт.  Возможно  было  какое-то  слово,  обозначающее  задние  ноги  животных.  Тогда  первично  не  просто   вертикальное  положение,  а  вертикальное  положение  четвероногих.

Answer (score 2):

Еще на дыбы ставят мотоцикл :)
Существует также выражение "волосы дыбом встали" от страха и т.п. Есть кузнечик дыбка степная. Для него характерно стоячее положение в ожидании жертвы. Все эти слова так или иначе указывают на вертикальное положение тела. В истории пыток существовало два вида дыбы: дыба-ложе и подвешивание. Причем дыба на Руси изначально - просто колодки (или колода). Интересно, какое значение появилось раньше: дыба в виде виселицы или лошадь, стоящая на задних ногах?

Comment: Неее, мотоцикл становится на "козла")))))

Comment: Я видела в интернете вопросы и советы "как поставить на дыбы мотоцикл". Кто их поймет, байкеров...